# How many isomorphism classes of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules of dimension six are there?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm trying to understand the idea of isomorphim classes of  $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules.
for example, how can i find the solution for this question:

> How many  $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ - modules $M$ exist such that $\operatorname{dim}(M) = 6$, up to **isomorphism**?

I’d tried to work with the fact that finite dimensional  $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules are completely reducible.

Comment: As you say, such a module is completely reducible.  So you just need to know how many irreducible modules there are of each dimension, up to isomorphism (it turns out there's one of each dimension 1,2,...).

Comment: I understand there's one **irreducible module** of each dimension but an sl2-module can be a direct sum of V(d) with different d’s, such that every d is an eigenvalue that corresponds to a primitive vector. So i don’t understand why there is just one module of dimension n up to isomorphism.

Comment: There's more than one module, one for each partition of 6.

Comment: I have rolled back an edit which made the title less informative

Comment: @Yemon Choi: The title still does not include the condition  $ \dim(M) = 6$, but includes a typo.

Comment: @user64494 the present title is imperfect, but your edit to that title made it worse on pretty much ever measure apart from punctuation. The point of good sub-editing is not to change the intended meaning, but to improve it, not to have some kind of Fowler-fetish

Comment: Christian Gaetz essentially answered the question. Have you been able to conclude?